# Why Go does not panic when trying to read from a nil map?

Tags: go

Here is the code, I expect it will panic when visiting `mp["12"]`, but it works fine there

```golang
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import "log"

func main() {
    var mp map[string]int = nil
    log.Println(mp["12"], "12") // works fine
    if mp == nil {
        panic("map is nil") // panic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Because that's [the way it's specified](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Map_types). `A nil map is equivalent to an empty map except that no elements may be added`

Comment: See also [Index expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Index_expressions): *"__if the map is nil__ or does not contain such an entry, __a[x] is the zero value__ for the element type of M"*

Comment: golang maps don't panic, when someone reads using a `[]` operator, even on a nil map. nil maps just cant be used to add any new elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read from a nil map, but cannot write to it. The language spec says:

> A nil map is equivalent to an empty map except that no elements may be added.